# How to copy an emoticon from Skype into HipChat?

Tags: gif, skype

Skype has a cute emoticon with flying hearts, produced by :].  Hipchat allows you to upload your own emoticons.  Now I need to extract the anumated GIF from Skype which is generated when you type :].  However, copy and paste returns only the original text.  How do I get the actual anumated GIF back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your GIF found [here?](http://factoryjoe.com/projects/emoticons/)

I guess you can just save it from your Browser

I don't know if this is the [Heart](http://factoryjoe.s3.amazonaws.com/emoticons/emoticon-0152-heart.gif) you are looking for.